# How do I express the Delphi operator "<>" in c++?

Tags: c++, delphi

I have had a tough time translating some Delphi code into c++. the code is :

```
if (GetWindowlong(Stringgrid1.Handle, GWL_STYLE) and WS_VSCROLL) <> 0
then ShowMessage('Vertical scrollbar is visible!');
```

Ive never really used Delphi before so im not sure what the "<>" operator is. I looked it up and found out that its called the pointer inequality operator, but im not sure how that translates into c++. Thanks a bunch for any help!

Comment: That's one of the *relational operators*, which are described in some detail in the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<> is just not-equals (similar to VB, for some silly reason). C++ uses != for pointer inequality like any other inequality.

Comment: C was the odd one out with `!`, but other languages copied it. <> is the mathematical operator for not equals, so most (Algol inspired) languages used it.

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent operator in C++: Not equal to: `!=`.

So the code should become something like:

```
if ((GetWindowlong(Stringgrid1.Handle, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VSCROLL) != 0) {
    ShowMessage('Vertical scrollbar is visible!');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `&&` ? Isn't it `&` ? (I don't know Delphi I cannot tell)

Comment: Then more idiomatic is `if (GetWindowlong(Stringgrid1.Handle, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VSCROLL)`.

Comment: @Alexandre C: Then he would have to come up with different sample code to show a use of !=.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` means different, and is equivalent to the `!=` operator in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The `<>` operator is spelled `!=` in C-derived languages and simply means inequality